# Why do I get "Module 'myControllers' is not available" in AngularJS even though I've already define it?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am following tutorial from https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/single and using structure from https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial.

But I got this error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ]

angular.js:4138 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myApp due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module myControllers due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'myControllers' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

app.js

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
    'ngRoute',
    'ngMessages',
    'myControllers'
]);

myApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 
    function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
     $routeProvider.
         when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
          controller: 'HomeCtrl'
         }).
      when('/login', {
       templateUrl: 'partials/login.html',
       controller: 'LoginCtrl'
      }).
      when('/register', {
       templateUrl: 'partials/register.html',
       controller: 'RegisterCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
      });
     
     $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common["X-Requested-With"] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
}]);
```

controllers.js

```js
var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers.controller('HomeCtrl', [ '$scope',
    function($scope) {
     console.log("HOME");

  //another code
    }]);

myControllers.controller('LoginCtrl', [ '$scope',
    function($scope) {
  console.log("LOGIN");

  //another code
    }]);

myControllers.controller('RegisterCtrl', [ '$scope',
    function($scope) {
  console.log("REGISTER");
    }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-messages.js"></script>
 
  
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you have a error o n line 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is error inside `LoginCtrl`.

Eclipse didn't said anything if there is error in my code and AngularJS error message is really misleading. As said in http://www.johnpapa.net/easy-fix-to-a-common-angular-module-error/, if this thing happened, make sure all of your code is correct.

and, using format from https://github.com/angular/angular-seed is better I think. I found it after I refactored my code from https:github.com/angular/angular-phonecat to https:github.com/angular/angular-seed